# **to reset iphone 6**(without connecting to itunes or without using home button)

Tags: iphone, restart

My iphone home button doesn't work and it doesn't turn on. It shows the apple symbol and doesn't start. Trying to hard reset the phone. Whenever I am connecting it to the itunes, it is asking for the permission from the phone(It wants me to allow Access) but I can not see anything but the apple symbol. Please tell me if there are any other ways to reset the phone without using the home button and connecting it to the itunes. I am trying to turn on my iphone by resetting the iphone.

Comment: Are you trying to reset to erase your iPhone or to get it to turn on?

Comment: I am trying to turn it on. The only option I find to turn it on is by resetting the iphone.